# Problem Installing OCUnit on my XCode 3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, macos, ocunit

I'm using XCode 3 to develop MAC and iPhone apps. Because I'm thinking of doing a major modification on the structure of two of my systems, I need first to make unit tests. As I browsed on the internet about the different possibilities and since neither of XCode's Text Bundle and GTM (Google Toolbox for MAC) worked, I'd give it a try with OCUnit. 
I downloaded and installed both the Home and Root packages of OCUnit and haven't find any changes on my XCode IDE.

Could someone guide me into installing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCUnit ships with Xcode 3. It's at `/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework`.

Comment: All right, but comparing with the screenshots on the manual, my IDE it's nothing compared to it. How can I set it up?